# Connecting multiple points in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

I just want to know how to connect multiple points on Google maps. I attached an image to be more clear on my objective. If i used poly line, it will look like connecting the dots. I want my map to display exactly like on the attached image.

Here is the link of the image:

[image]

Comment: How are you going to get the lat and long of those points at the first place?

Comment: as of now, the lat and long are user inputted but i'm planning to get the lat and long on the database..

Comment: but what is your main objective? are yoiu trying to get driving directions?

Comment: No, I want to display the route itself. For example, there are 4 points namely A,B,C,D. Now I want to see the route from A to B, B to C, C to D.